# nullifying MediaPlayer in onCompletion method in Android is not working

Tags: java, android, media-player

I am trying to use onCompletion method to rest, release and nullify the MediaPlayer.
I am doing this as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (player1 == null) {
            player1 = new MediaPlayer();
            player1.setVolume(10, 10);
            player1.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        }


        switch (v.getId()) {
               .
               . 
               .

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player1) {
        player1.reset();
        player1.release();
        player1 = null;
                .
                .
                .
```

However, when I try to debug in Eclips, I see that player1 is not "null". Can somebody please let me know how shall I pass player1 so that I can make it "null".

Thank you very much for the help.

TJ

Comment: try to use `this.player1=null` as in onCompletion event you are setting null to local variable, while in onClick event you are checking member variable, it is not visible currently in the above code but my guess.

Comment: Hi Asad, Thank you very much. your are right and your suggestion worked nicely.

Comment: Asad: I want to accept your answer but I do not see any accept sign. Please let me know how can I accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I have posted above comment as an answer, now you can accept it. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `this.player1=null` as in onCompletion event you are setting null to local variable, while in onClick event you are checking member variable, it is not visible currently in the above code but my guess.